# Ubuntu 18.04 Dual Boot With Windows 10: Audio Issues

Tags: boot, dual-boot, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

everyone. I've recently installed on an SSD that's shared with Windows. Everything seems to run fine except the audio. If I plug in a USB-C hub that includes an audio jack, and set that as audio output in System settings, the audio is perfect. However, whenever I try to use my laptop's builtin audio jack, the audio seems to break. It is completely silent, except when I increase audio to max. When I do that, it's still silent for the most part, with intermittent bouts of sound that high pitched and completely unintelligible. Audio works perfectly fine in Windows 10.

I've tried rebooting my computer into Windows 10, shutting down, and cold booting into Ubuntu. I've also tried killing PulseAudio, force restarting Alsa, reinstalling Alsa and PulseAudio, suspending Ubuntu, and have even resorted to reinstalling the entire OS, yet this problem still persists. Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

For reference, my laptop is the Asus Zenbook S. 
Intel i7 8550K 
Intel UHD Graphics 620
16GB of RAM
512GB NvME PCIE SSD

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to boot to windows, remove ubuntu partition and when everything is perfect with your audiodrivers again reinstall ubuntu..Also you can check [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/1dydtz/linuxwindows_dual_boot_audio_problem/)
Hope this help you with your problem..Thankyou

Comment: I deleted the partition before I reinstalled Ubuntu. The audio works perfectly in Windows. The problem arises when I boot into Ubuntu. I tried the solutions mentioned in that thread. I shut down Windows, and I cold booted into Ubuntu, yet the audio issues still persisted.

Comment: Have you repaired your windows after removing the ubuntu partition..??

Comment: If you have not done that then grub will still be there in you bootloader..Check this to perfectly remove the linux and grub [link](https://itsfoss.com/uninstall-ubuntu-linux-windows-dual-boot/)

Comment: I deleted the grub loader in the UEFI partition, and removed it as a boot option in my BIOS. Plus, this issue occurred on the first install anyway.